# IOS: AVAudioPlayer stop and play

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have this code:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  @"change.mp3"];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
change = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
[change prepareToPlay];
```

I write in this code in viewdidload; 
now with a button I start this sound, but if I press the same button, I want to stop this sound and restart the sound; I try this code inside IBAction but it don't work

```
[change stop];
[change prepareToPlay];
[change play];
```

what can I do?

Comment: `prepareToPlay` has a return value.  If it returns "`NO`", that means a failure.  Is `change` the same object as in your `viewDidLoad:` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this:

```
[change pause];
change.currentTime = 0.0;
[change play];
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW7) of the method `-stop` says:

> The stop method does not reset the value of the currentTime property to 0. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call play, playback resumes at the point where it left off.

So you have to use the property `currentTime` and set it to `0`:

```
[change pause];
[change setCurrentTime:0];
[change play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make initialization again? I mean first `[change release]` and init it.